# accessing sharepoint help desk list items via web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site based on the help desk (call center) template, and although I can access other lists with the Lists.GetListItems() method described on MSDN, I cannot get at the Service Requests list items.

Can someone explain to me how the Service Requests lists differs from normal lists, and what I need to do to get at it?

I think it might have something to do with Content Types - "This list is configured to allow multiple content types."

My Service Request list currently only has "Service Request (Call Center)" as an allowed content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste everyone's time.

The problem was that this was a subsite, and even though I put the full URL in when creating the Web Reference, when it got put into the App.config, it was shortened to the top level site URL.

When I modified it and put in the full URL, it started working.